# Showing user friendly information while receiving contact requests on MSN XMPP

Tags: xmpp, msn-messenger

In Msn the jid of the user is different than the email id.

Now , when i receive any contact requests on Msn , I only get the sender's jid which is something like @messenger.live.com . This does not give any idea to the user who the sender of the contact request is .

Is there any way whereby we can display some user friendly information , so that the receiver of the contact request can make an informed decision whether to accept/decline the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explore following links, it may help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh550849.aspx

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html

Comment: They include a stanza 'nick' as a child of the 'presence' stanza which has the nickName of the sender as the content.